# Crossing Circles

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, circles

On a plane, you are only allowed to draw circles. After drawing 1 circle, can you ALWAYS draw another so that the new circle crosses all existing circles at 2 points? Why?

Comment: Do all the circles have to be the same radius?

Comment: What do you mean "all existing circles at 2 points"? Do you mean the total number of intersection with all existing circles is 2 or the new circle intersect every existing circle at 2 points (i.e n old circles gives you 2n new intersections).

Comment: If it's the later, what about something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/eGyE6io.png)?

Comment: @jamisans If the latter interpretation is what is desired, then there is not way to construct that picture following this process in the first place.

Comment: I took the question to mean there was a starting configuration of circles and then you had to draw a circle crossing them all twice. But if it's meant to be an iterative process, then yes, that picture isn't useful.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified. You start with one circle... Then you have to add another so it intersects with the first at two points... Then, you must add a third so it intersects with both the first and the second at two points each... Can you continue this process infinitely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be seen by taking a circle of any radius, but lets say one, centered at $(\frac{1}{2},0)$.  Then take a copy of that circle, and rotate it $180^ \circ$.

[image: two circles of radius 1, intersecting on the y axis]

Then you repeat this process, placing as many circles as you want between them, in the top or bottom of the plane.  It could look something like this, which is only 4 circles, but more is harder to tell what is going on.

[image: four circles, all intersecting each other]

This can be done as long as they all contain the same interior point and have the same radius. For our example, they all contain the origin.

Comment: If, instead of spacing the centers of the circles equally around the origin, you put them at $\pi,\frac\pi2, \frac\pi3, \ldots$ radians around the origin, then you would be able to place arbitrarily many circles, without knowing ahead of time how many would be required.